# table not updating while using functions in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I made a python program which takes arguments from function call to update a table. The arguments are passed successfully but Does not update the table.
`

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user='root',passwd="",database='student')
print(mydb)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("create TABLE if not exists testtable ( num INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,issue varchar(30), status varchar(30),PRIMARY KEY (num))")


def dev(y,z):
    values=(y,z)
    print(values)
    print(mydb)
    sql = "UPDATE form SET status = %s WHERE num = %s"
    mycursor.execute(sql,values)
    mydb.commit()
    print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
values=('goog',1)
sql = "UPDATE form SET status = %s WHERE num = %s"
mycursor.execute(sql,values)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
dev('goog',2)`
```

a similar query outside the function works properly.
For some reason mycursor.execute() wont execute

Comment: `print(mycursor)` inside a function and outside

Comment: @py_dude o/p : `MySQLCursor: UPDATE form SET issue = 'googl' WHERE nu..` `outside MySQLCursor: create TABLE if not exists testtable ( n..`